# A rectangle drawn with DrawingContext.DrawRectangle blocks mouse

Tags: c#, wpf

The WPF program below puts up a window which looks like this:

[image]

Mouse-movement outside the black square causes the window title to be updated with the mouse's position. The updating stops when the mouse enters the square.

I'd like for `MouseMove` to continue to trigger even when the mouse is over the square. Is there a way to do this?

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Wpf_Particle_Demo
{
    class DrawingVisualElement : FrameworkElement
    {
        public DrawingVisual visual;

        public DrawingVisualElement() { visual = new DrawingVisual(); }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return 1; } }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) { return visual; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var canvas = new Canvas();

            Content = canvas;

            var element = new DrawingVisualElement();

            canvas.Children.Add(element);

            CompositionTarget.Rendering += (s, e) =>
                {
                    using (var dc = element.visual.RenderOpen())
                        dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50));
                };

            MouseMove += (s, e) => Title = e.GetPosition(canvas).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using such a bizarre code to draw a rectangle? why not just do a rectangle object in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to [Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591452%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the mouse this will allow your `Canvas` to continue to respond to the `MouseMove` Event, Try something like this it will update your coordinates as long as the Mouse is Pressed

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var canvas = new Canvas();
        Content = canvas;

        var element = new DrawingVisualElement();

        canvas.Children.Add(element);
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += (s, e) =>
        {
            using (var dc = element.visual.RenderOpen())
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50));
        };

        Mouse.Capture(canvas);
        MouseDown += (s, e) => Mouse.Capture((UIElement)s);
        MouseMove += (s, e) => Title = e.GetPosition(canvas).ToString();
        MouseUp += (s, e) => Mouse.Capture(null);

    }
```

---

**Second Method**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var canvas = new Canvas();
    Content = canvas;

    DrawingVisualElement element = new DrawingVisualElement();
    Grid myElement = new Grid();
    canvas.Children.Add(myElement);

    CompositionTarget.Rendering += (s, e) =>
    {
        using (var dc = element.visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(100, 0, 50, 50));
        }

        DrawingImage myImage = new DrawingImage(element.visual.Drawing);
        myElement.Height = myImage.Height;
        myElement.Width = myImage.Width;
        myElement.Background = new ImageBrush(myImage);
    };


    MouseMove += (s, e) => Title = e.GetPosition(canvas).ToString();
}
```

---

**Using a Hook**   be sure to put a `using System.Windows.Interop;`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var canvas = new Canvas();
        Content = canvas;

        var element = new DrawingVisualElement();
        canvas.Children.Add(element);

        CompositionTarget.Rendering += (s, e) =>
        {
            using (var dc = element.visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50));
            }
        };
        this.SourceInitialized += new EventHandler(OnSourceInitialized);
    }

    void OnSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HwndSource source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
        source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(HandleMessages));

    }
    IntPtr HandleMessages(IntPtr hwnd, int msg,IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == 0x200)
            Title = Mouse.GetPosition(this).ToString(); // because I did not want to split the lParam into High/Low values for Position information
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, Thanks Mark. I'd like to accomplish this without having a mouse button pressed. I was able to do so by putting the `Mouse.Capture` in the `MouseMove` event handler. However, then interesting things happen... For example, not being able to close the window using the mouse! :-) Also, the title get's updated even when the mouse moves outside the canvas, e.g. into the window title.

Comment: @dharmatech This problem kept me playing most of the afternoon, I have another example that works using a Grid as a Container, also an example intercepting the WM_MOUSEMOVE Method. I will post them see if they work

Comment: This is actually for a [particle demo](https://gist.github.com/4053350). I worked around the problem by drawing the black background as a `Rectangle` shape instead of with the `DrawingContext`. But there are other cases where that workaround wouldn't work well. So I'm still interested in a solution. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @dharmatech I am curious, which one looked the best to you?

Comment: For this case, I ended up sticking with using a `Rectangle` shape for the background. I like the first and second methods you presented though. It seems like they each would be applicable in certain circumstances. I.e. there are cases where it would be natural to capture the mouse. My reason for using a `DrawingContext` instead of shapes is that shapes have much more overhead. The second method (using `DrawingImage`) seems to reintroduce overhead for every item drawn. The first method doesn't have the overhead drawback (just the downsides of capturing the mouse from other handlers).

Answer (score 3):

By far the simplest way is to use the "tunneling" event on the window, PreviewMouseDown.  It is delivered to the window first and works its way up the hierarchy.  So it doesn't matter at all which other elements you have in the window.  In code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window {
    public Window1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Window1_PreviewMouseMove);
    }
    void Window1_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        this.Title = e.GetPosition(this).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the example program, I changed `MouseMove` to `PreviewMouseMove` but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so much easier. All you need is to set element.IsHitTestVisible=false;